# How to remove html injection from my website

Tags: php, html, code-injection, spam-prevention

Today I was looking for my cached page of my website then I find that Google indexed lot of spammy pages which I cannot find in my website.

My website is a college website but in Google there are pages of "*nike air max 95 at jd sports*" and all my url's are rewrite but in Google it showing a new url (this is similar like my URL: http://example.com/?nike-max-air-343.html).

When I try to find this page in my website I didn't find any of these pages. Kindly provide me any possible solutions so the Google can't list a

> "This site maybe Hacked"

message on SERP.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this happended to me I started the lookforbadguys.php script, you can find here

https://gist.github.com/jasperf/3191259

Copy this file into the DOCUMENT_ROOT of your page and then call in browser

http://example.com/lookforbadguys.php

It then scans your file-system under document root for suscpicious file names and code

It may create a long list of hits, and you have to check every single one (if you don't know exactly that you made it yourself). This is tedious, but I works.

One little hint: Save the output of the scan as html file and open that file in browser. This prevents the script to scan on reload.

After that you must identify the security holes of your server.
You may have to update installed software and/or your scripts.

Comment: i find this code in directory

home/Example/public_html/Example/phpexcel180/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php

Comment: public static function _GetInt4d($data, $pos)

                {

                                // FIX: represent numbers correctly on 64-bit system
// http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1487372&group_id=99160&atid=623334

                                // Hacked by Andreas Rehm 2006 to ensure correct result of the <<24 block on 32 and 64bit systems
$_or_24 = ord($data[$pos + 3]);

                                if ($_or_24 >= 128) {

Comment: // negative number

                                                $_ord_24 = -abs((256 - $_or_24) << 24);

                                } else {

                                                $_ord_24 = ($_or_24 & 127) << 24;

                                }

                                return ord($data[$pos]) | (ord($data[$pos+1]) << 8) | (ord($data[$pos+2]) << 16) | $_ord_24;

                }

Comment: Sorry for this kind of comment but i have to tell this is the code which i find in my file. please tell me what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to do anything.  I had a similar warning today.

"Hacked by Andreas Rehm 2006..." seems to be part of the source code for the file on line# 353
[Source for file OLERead.php on grad.clemson.edu](https://www.clemson.edu/graduate/)